# Provide activeFocus to Flickable

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML component with a **Flickable** list and I need this Flickable to get **activeFocus** when I am clicking on it. I am trying to do it with MouseArea, but can't figure out how to make it work.

My tries:

```
FocusScope {
    id: root
    implicitHeight: 100
    implicitWidth: 100
    
    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        onActiveFocusChanged: console.log("Work!")
        ...
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            flickable.forceActiveFocus()
            mouse.accepted = false
        }
        preventStealing: true
    }
}
```

```
FocusScope {
    id: root
    implicitHeight: 100
    implicitWidth: 100

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: flickable.forceActiveFocus()
        Flickable {
            id: flickable
            anchors.fill: parent
            onActiveFocusChanged: console.log("Work!")
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the first variant, my flickable is working, but MouseArea is not handling the click. In the second one, Flickable is not working, but MouseArea is handling the click.

So the question is how to correctly set activeFocus of Flickable on the click event?

Comment: why did you put Flickable inside a FocusScope?

Comment: for getting key events correctly

Answer (score 0):

Write **id** for your Flickable

and also Try this code :

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

FocusScope {
id: root
width: 640
height: 480

Flickable {
    id:flickable
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    contentHeight: mColumnId.implicitHeight

    onActiveFocusChanged: console.log("Work!")

    Column{
        id : mColumnId
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            width: parent.width
            height: 200
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Element 1"
                font.pointSize: 30
                color : "white"
            }
        }


        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            width: parent.width
            height: 200
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Element 2"
                font.pointSize: 30
                color : "white"
            }
        }



        Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
            width: parent.width
            height: 200
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Element 3"
                font.pointSize: 30
                color : "white"
            }
        }

    }


    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            flickable.forceActiveFocus()
            mouse.accepted = false
            preventStealing: true
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: I just forgot to write it in the question, in my code I have it. So this way the flickable is not going to flick. U can check this out with filling Flickable with some content

Comment: Remove `preventStealing: true` line from MouseArea and also Remove `FocusScope`

Comment: I edit my answer , try this it may help you.

Comment: I add some Elements in Flickable to see what happens and also add `contentHeight: mColumnId.implicitHeight` in Flickable , and change MouseArea and put it inside Flickable . It works for me but please check and tell me , Is  that  what you want?

Comment: Well, yes, it's working when mouseArea is inside the flickable, but I guess it's not the proper way for the production code. I think mouseArea should be the parent of Flickable, but don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Why mouseArea should be parent?